# linux read intermittent stream from streaming function

Tags: linux, stream, zsh

-- **UPDATE**: This has been solved but I am leaving the original question for clarity; read "ADDED" at bottom --

I am having difficulty implementing (and also TBH grasping the concept of) streaming in bash.  There is a specific command in `kubectl` that will stream updates live (this is just an example, this is not a kubernetes question).  I would like to read these and process them.

In order to keep it dirt simple at first I tried the following:

```
output_some_lines() {
    while ; do
        echo "a"
        # break
    done
}

output_some_lines_better() {
    echo starting..
    # this does not work..
    #    while read line; do
    #       echo "$line b"
    #    done; < <(output_some_lines 2>&1)
    
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "$line b"
    done < <(unbuffer `output_some_lines` 2>&1)
    
    echo done!
}
```

Running `output_some_lines` works as expected.  However I would expect running `output_some_lines_better` to get

```
a b
a b
a b
a b
a b
... etc
```

but I see no output (obviously because the script is still running).  You can see the first failure (commented out), and the second try was something I saw suggested.  But neither are working.  How do I get the `a b` stream at least here, and will I then need to modify plugging in the kube command `kubectl get pods -n rias -w -o json`?  And any input on working with streams would really be appreciated.

-- ADDED --
it turns out that thanks to @M.NejatAydin comment removing the `;` from the commented-out attempt `done; < <(..` resolved the problem and that makes sense.  I was then able to make this work with the `kubectl` command:

```
output_kube_command() {
    kubectl get pods -n rias -w -o json
}

output_some_lines_better() {
    while read line; do
        echo "$line b"
    done < <(output_kube_command 2>&1)
}
```

Comment: `while ; do` must be a syntax error. Very likely you meant `while true; do` or `while : ; do`. Also, remove the `;` from `done; < <(output_some_lines 2>&1)` and then that loop should work.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin thank you.  The `while ;` seemed to have worked just fine though `while true;` looks cleaner.  However removing the `; ` from the `done; < <` made it work with a stream of "a b" lines. HOWEVER, replacing `output_some_lines` with the `kubectl get pods -n rias -w -o json` still did not produce an output stream, any idea why?

Comment: well, it is working ;) perhaps because I'm using `/bin/zsh` - not experienced enough to know for sure

Comment: `zsh` is a different shell from `bash`, with which the question is tagged. So all bets are off for me since I don't have a clue about `zsh`.

Comment: my apologies for obscuring the thread, I have re-tagged it with `zsh`